# how to get only one object from a bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

I need to get only one object at a time from S3 bucket..
And I only found the API to get all the objects in a bucket.. is there a way to get only one?
I'm gonna use a certain position or index to get one object at a time.

```html
    result, err := w.Client.ListObjectsV2(ctx, input)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Got an error retrieving objects:")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    for _, item := range result.Contents {
        fmt.Println("Name:          ", *item.Key)
        fmt.Println("Last modified: ", *item.LastModified)
        fmt.Println("Size:          ", item.Size)
        fmt.Println("Storage class: ", item.StorageClass)
        fmt.Println("")
    }
```

Comment: Does this work for you?
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.35.36/service/s3#S3.GetObject

Comment: What do you mean by "get only one object"? The `ListObjects()` command simply returns a _listing_ of objects, not the objects themselves. Are you not able to loop through the list that is returned, and process them one-at-a-time?

Comment: You can indicate MaxKeys=1 and use either StartAfter or ContinuationToken for subsequent list requests, but I would question why you want to do this in the first place.

Comment: I only need one object at a time.. and I don't want to get all the object and only use one because this would be a waste of time and space @JohnRotenstein

Comment: @EminLaletovic oh thank you! but this seems to be version 1 of the sdk.. I'm using v2

Comment: @jarmod I think this would solve the problem! thank you so much

Comment: It would be a greater "waste of time and space" to make multiple API calls to Amazon S3 to list one object at a time. It is much faster and more efficient to obtain the listing in one API call, then do whatever you wish with each object. It's a bit like running to the supermarket for one item at a time, rather than having a single shopping list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request a maximum number of S3 keys to be returned by indicating MaxKeys=1 in your [ListObjectsV2Input](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#ListObjectsV2Input):

> MaxKeys: Sets the maximum number of keys returned in the response. By default the action returns up to 1,000 key names. The response might contain fewer keys but will never contain more.

To get the next S3 key, you would use either `StartAfter` or `ContinuationToken` in your subsequent ListObjectsV2 request.